# Subsetting data by multiple values in multiple variables in R

Tags: r

Lets say I have this dataset:

```
data1 = sample(1:250, 250)
data2 = sample(1:250, 250)
data <- data.frame(data1,data2)
```

If I want to subset 'data' by 30 values in both 'data1' and 'data2' what would be the best way to do that? For example, from 'data' I want to select all rows where data1= 4 or 12 or 13 or 24 and data2= 4 or 12 or 13 or 24 and data2= 4 or 12 or 13 or 24. I want rows where both conditions are true.

I wrote this out like:

```
subdata <- subset(data, data1 == 4 |data1 == 12 |data1 == 13 |data1 == 24 & data2 == 4 |data2 == 12 |data2 == 13 |data2 == 24)
```

But this doesn't seem meet both conditions, rather it's one or the other.

Comment: You are looking for `%in%`: Something close would be `dat[dat$data1 %in% c(4, 12, 13) & dat$data2 %in% c(4, 12, 13), ]`. Just adjust to your exact needs. It is discouraged to use the same names as existing R objects as it can lead to confusion. `data` is an existing function.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in your original `subset`, you didn't wrap your `|` tests for `data1` and `data2` in brackets. This produces the wrong subset of "data1= 4 or 12 or 13 or 24 *OR* data2= 4 or 12 or 13 or 24". You actually want:

```
subdata <- subset(data, (data1 == 4 |data1 == 12 |data1 == 13 |data1 == 24) & (data2 == 4 |data2 == 12 |data2 == 13 |data2 == 24))
```

Here is how you would modify your `subset` function with `%in%`:

```
subdata <- subset(data, (data1 %in% c(4, 12, 13, 24)) & (data2 %in% c(4, 12, 13, 24)))
```

Below I provide an elegant `dplyr` approach with `filter_all`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(. %in% c(4, 12, 13, 24)))
```

**Note:**

Your `sample` functions do not easily produce sample data where the tests are actually true. As a result the above solution would likely return zero rows. I've therefore modified your sample dataset to produce rows that actually have matches that you can subset.

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1)
data1 = sample(c(4, 12, 13, 24, 100, 123), 500, replace = TRUE)
data2 = sample(c(4, 12, 13, 24, 100, 123), 500, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(data1,data2)
```

Comment: @ArielKaputkin If you think that this answer is helpful, do consider accepting it by clicking on the grey check mark under the downvote button :)